# Spring elasticsearch merge documents from two different indexes

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am new to elastic-search and i am trying to use spring data elastic search in the application.
I have a requirement where in there are two separate indexes and i want to fetch documents from both indexes in one query based on some condition.

I would try to explain it with sample example with the same scenario.
There are two Different classes for individual indexes.

```
@Document(indexName = "Book", type = "Book")
public class Book {

@Id
private String id;

@Field(type = FieldType.String)
private String bookName;

@Field(type = FieldType.Integer)
private int price;

@Field(type = FieldType.String)
private String authorName;

//Getters and Setters

}
```

There is one more class Author

```
@Document(indexName = "Author", type = "Author")
public Class Author{

@Id
private String id;

@Field(type = FieldType.String)
private String authorName;

//Getters and setters
}
```

So there are two indexes one Book and Other Author.
**I want to fetch all the documents where authorName in Book index is equal to authorName in Author index.

Can i get the details from both the index as a single document like merged result.**
It would be very helpful if anyone can suggest solution for this usecase.

Thanks & Regards
 Sumanth